# how to improve flutter http requests

Tags: flutter, http, timeout

i use http package in my flutter app to sen and recieve data, but unfortually most of the time i don't get a respond which make my app crashs or stuck in loading forever.
How can i improve request handling and especially how to resend another request automatically when the previous fails.

This is how i send a request

```
 try {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://${code
      }/Api/public/api/testConnection"),
      headers: {
        "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5"
      }
  ).timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 10),
  );

 connection=true;


} catch (e) {

 connection=false;

}
```

the problem is not from the server because i tried post man and it never failed, it just fails in my app

Answer (score 1):

Its better if u use **RetryClient** to resend requests when first request fails.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

http.Response? response;
var _client = RetryClient(http.Client(), retries: 2);

response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse("http://${code
  }/TusApi/public/api/testConnection"),
  headers: {
    "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=1"
  }
).timeout(
  const Duration(seconds: 10),
);
if (response?.statusCode != 200) {
  response = await _client.get(url, headers: header);
}
```

In addition, its better if you increase your timeout duration more than 10 seconds.